# In which version of iOS did the 'high speed scrubbing' *prompt* appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, media-player

iOS has had high speed scrubbing in the media player since iOS3. However, the prompt which appears below the scrubbing control ("Slide your finger down to adjust the scrubbing rate") appeared at some later point. For example, an iPhone I have running iOS3.1.3 doesn't show the scrubbing prompt while you scrub.

So when did the prompt first appear?

Comment: I'm thinking the answer will be iOS3.2, since that was the major overhaul of the movie player. But I can't verify this myself, or find it documented on the web.

Comment: iOS 3.2 was never released on the iPhone or iPod Touch.  iOS 3.2 was only released on the iPad.

Comment: so for iPhone it would be 4.0 since that is when alot of the new things in 3.2 (like the movie player rehaul) were introduced to iPhone/iPodTouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "Slide your finger down to adjust the scrubbing rate" first appeared in the source of iOS 3.2.